# Google Calendar Api watch creates watcher, but it doesn't work

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api, webhooks

My server doesn't receive the changes from Google Calendar, although, watcher is created.
I did this solution with the same code half a year ago, and it worked. But now it doesn't.
I searched the users solutions, but all of them said, that the problem may be in Google's servers.
I use Ngrok, that points to my local server, for receiving notifications. I tried ngrok endpoint, I receive the requests (tried with Postman - both GET and POST)
Please, tell me possible solutions - maybe I'm wrong.
Thanks in advance!

I'll provide the code I used below.

```
import json
import os.path
import uuid

from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from scopes_ import SCOPES

def main():
creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)

# https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/watch
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
channel = {
'id': str(uuid.uuid4()),
"address": 'https://687a-212-111-193-44.eu.ngrok.io/test_watch/',
'type': 'web_hook',
'params': {
'ttl': '36000'
}
}

res = service.events().watch(calendarId='primary', body=channel).execute()
print(res)


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Google Calendar API watcher will send the calendar's changes (webhooks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone will face this error in the future: for some reason ngrok server doesn't work, so I replaced it with my own server (instead of `https://687a-212-111-193-44.eu.ngrok.io/test_watch/` I use `https://my-server.com/test_watch/`). Now it works properly. Not sure, why is that happening.

I read on the Internet, that you should register ngrok domain on https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/start like `687a-212-111-193-44.eu.ngrok.io`, but didn't test it.

**Update:**
I found another service, like ngrok - pretty convenient and free (that's important). It's called [serveo.net](https://serveo.net/). It works great. Not sure, maybe they have block for ngrok ;)